# Is a complete list of Vimeo's advanced statistics available?

Tags: video-streaming, vimeo

I am interested in getting a list of the advanced statistics available on Vimeo.

Here is the text from their site:

> With Advanced Statistics you can stay on top of all your statistics, look at your >weekly, monthly and yearly stats, see where people are watching your videos, and find >people who like or comment on your videos.

but it does not state anywhere I can find exactly what measures are included in the weekly, monthly, yearly stats.  I am particularly interested in Viewer engagement stats to aid content creators in continuous improvement of our video/webinar content.

Is the point at which a particular user stopped the video or if it was watched to completion included?

Answer (score 1):

The stats are visible on videos when you watch them on the site.  There are no user engagement metrics clearly available from this view, but it is not clear if these stats are the "Advanced Statistics" from the marketing blurb, or if there may be engagement metrics in a different view/area of the site.

[image: Vimeo Stats]